# Getting this error "ERROR: java.io.IOException: Agent is unreachable via TCP" jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector in jemeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

Why am I getting the following error in `PerfMon jmeter plugin`?

> "ERROR: java.io.IOException: Agent is unreachable via TCP"
>   how to configure perfmon plugin in Jmeter 4.0 version

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure to install [Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) to the server you want to monitor and launch it
2. Make sure that default port of `4444` is open for TCP and UDP traffic in your operating system firewall.
3. In order to test connectivity you can send `test` message to the Server Agent using [Telnet client](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026) software (you can use [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) if you don't have any Telnet client installed). If everything is fine you should see `Yep` response. JMeter should be able to connect to the Server Agent and collect the metrics of your choice:

   [image: JMeter Test PerfMon]

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed Answer

Comment: I have checked it, i did not run server Agent at server side.

Comment: After run server agent at server machine and ran test get the connection using 4444 port.